# How to make phone calls using Python?

Tags: python, usb, voice

I'm writting a small python program to send voice file to other telephone. The phone is connected to pc over usb. How to make phone calls using Python?

Comment: @Jean-Pierre, Please explain more, 
what kind of phone are u talking about (the make,the model)...
is your second question related to the first one.

Comment: How much effort did you make to solve this problem yourself? Your question embodies a huge number of very distinct programming issues, and I have the impression that you haven't put much of your own effort into it.

Comment: I'm trying to send a voice file over mobile telephone (nokia 6300 or others) to other mobile telephone which are connected to pc. Second mobile telephone accept file and save it in the computer

Answer (score 2):

I think the smart way is to leave it a professional Voice/IP app such as ribbit or Twilio. I would personally recommend twilio which has Python libraries

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the [pyusb](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pyusb/index.php?title=Main_Page) library.